# How to write a python script to get the IP and IPs the of the routers to which my Windows OS computer is connected and also the device name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

For example, I have connected to a LAN using the ethernet cable and to the internet using the WiFi. My computer has got 2 more interfaces that are currently not used.

The script should check for only active interfaces and return their IPs, router IPs, and the device names.

[image: ip config screen]

Comment: https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: @tblev can we use it in a application though?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [netifaces](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/).  Like this:

```py
import netifaces as ni

for iface in ni.interfaces():
    print('interface : {0}'.format(iface))
    try:
        addrs = ni.ifaddresses(iface)
        for k, v in addrs[ni.AF_INET][0].items():
            print('   {0} : {1}'.format(k, v))
    except:
        pass

gways = ni.gateways()
print('gateway: {0}'.format(gways['default'][ni.AF_INET][0]))
```